# ActivityAware.onAttachedToActivity is not triggered

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I'm trying to port **Zendesk Native SDK** for **Android** in Flutter using MethodChannel and **Kotlin** as my language choice.

It works when I use the Kotlin code directly inside the project which is

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

  // others code are hidden

  private fun initialize(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    val url: String = call.argument("url")!!
    val appId: String = call.argument("appId")!!
    val clientId: String = call.argument("clientId")!!

    Zendesk.INSTANCE.init(this, url, appId, clientId)
    val identity = AnonymousIdentity()
    Zendesk.INSTANCE.setIdentity(identity)
    Support.INSTANCE.init(Zendesk.INSTANCE)

    RequestListActivity.builder().show(this)
    result.success(true)
  }
}
```

The `this` is referring to `Activity` which I guess `FlutterApplication` already has inside of it, but when I try to make the standalone `plugin` thing is a little bit different. I need to implement `ActivityAware` to get the activity ([Get activity reference in flutter plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887901/get-activity-reference-in-flutter-plugin)).

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Create-Flutter-Plugin

> (Optional) If your plugin needs an Activity reference, also implement ActivityAware.

```
public class ZendeskPlugin : FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware {
  private lateinit var activityBinding: ActivityPluginBinding

  // I can get ActivityPluginBinding from this method
  override fun onAttachedToActivity(@NonNull binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
    activityBinding = binding
  }

  private fun initialize(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    activityBinding?.activity?.let {
      val appId: String = call.argument("appId")!!
      val clientId: String = call.argument("clientId")!!
      val url: String = call.argument("url")!!

      Zendesk.INSTANCE.init(it, url, appId, clientId)
      val identity = AnonymousIdentity()
      Zendesk.INSTANCE.setIdentity(identity)
      Support.INSTANCE.init(Zendesk.INSTANCE)

      RequestListActivity.builder().show(it)
      result.success(true)
      return
    }

    result.error("INITIALIZE_FAILED", "Failed to initialize", null)
  }
}
```

I tried to call `initialize` from dart and actually it runs but `onAttachedToActivity` seems is never be invoked and makes `activityBinding` is never be initialized so the code fails and `result.error`.

How do I get activity inside `FlutterPlugin` class?
Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem with you, have you solved it?

Comment: Temporary, yes, although I added some code in `Runner/AppDelegate.swift` [see ref 1] to make it able to get `UINavigationController` [see ref 2]. -- 

Please let me know if you have other solution in the future haha

-- refs:
[1] https://pastebin.com/iE7K96ci
[2] https://github.com/wahyoo/flutter_zendesk/blob/9d8b0f81a51b8649e7c3aec29f0ad2abe524ff01/ios/Classes/SwiftZendeskPlugin.swift#L131

Comment: Your question is all about Android, but in your comment above you talk about iOS? Am I confused or is comment wrong/ irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is the call of the **setMethodCallHandler** in the **onAttachedToEngine**

Look more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66268739/10140197)